# Replacing regexp patterns with different values

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this:

```
text = "bla bla bla\n {panel:title=Realisation|borderStyle=dashed|borderColor=#cccccc|titleBGColor=#a39d9d}\n bla bla bla\n {panel:title=Definition of Done|borderStyle=dashed|borderColor=#cccccc|titleBGColor=#a39d9d} bla bla
```

and i need replace {panel:title=Realisation|borderStyle=dashed|borderColor=#cccccc|titleBGColor=#a39d9d} to Realisation and {panel:title=Definition of Done|borderStyle=dashed|borderColor=#cccccc|titleBGColor=#a39d9d} to Definition of Done

I tried to do it like this

```
def del_tags(text):
    if text:
        CLEANR = re.compile('{panel.*?}')
        try:
            TITLES = re.search('title\=(.+?)\|', text).group(1)
        except AttributeError:
            TITLES = ""
        cleantext = re.sub(CLEANR, TITLES, text)
        return cleantext
    else: 
        return text
```

But they replace everything with Realisation.

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

text = "bla bla bla\n{panel:title=Realisation|borderStyle=dashed|borderColor=#cccccc|titleBGColor=#a39d9d}\nbla bla bla\n{panel:title=Definition of Done|borderStyle=dashed|borderColor=#cccccc|titleBGColor=#a39d9d} bla bla"

text = re.sub(r"{panel:title=([^|}]+).*?}", r"\1", text)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
bla bla bla
Realisation
bla bla bla
Definition of Done bla bla
```

---

`{panel:title=([^|}]+).*?}` will match title after the `panel:title=` and substitute the whole `{...}` - [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uANKjl/1)